# MYSQL Limit Math

Tags: php, mysql

Let say i've database table (my_table) where i'm going to store id's

Now i want to divide the count of id's into 3 parts say `x,y,z`

then calling it 3 times each time with limit from/to

```
1 to x
x+1 to y
y+1 to z
```

Example :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS allids FROM my_table";
$cus = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql);
$cuss = mysql_fetch_array($cus);
```

Now `$z = $cuss['allids']; // All`

I want to say

```
$qry="select * from my_table where id='". rand(1,$x)."'";
```

and

```
$qry="select * from my_table where id='". rand($x+1,$y)."'";
```

and

```
$qry="select * from my_table where id='". rand($y+1,$z)."'";
```

Got the idea, i'm going to call it in certain range

### Mathematical Problem

I do not know how exactly how is the total id's also it could be even or add so i need
the important is each one does not show results conflict with the other calling.

Any idea

Example : let say the total `id's = 9` then i'll divide it on 3 so

```
X = 9/3 = 3
z = 9 (all)
y = z - x = 9 - 3 = 6
```

then we can get

```
rand (1,x) = (1,3)
rand (x+3,y) = (4,6)
rand (y+1,z) = (7,9)
```

What if the total id's was even or odd ?!

Comment: I'm assuming that for every possible id there is a row? I mean, there are no skipped ids?

Comment: this is just example , i'm asking about if we get the total id's then how can divided it into 3 regions x,y,z and what if the total is even or odd ! Example : let say total id's = 9 then 9/3= 3 then z=9 (total) and x = 3 and y = 9-3 = 6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id BETWEEN x and y ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: the problem is that what is x and what is y ? how we can calculate its value !

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) AS c FROM my_table` you have the total number of rows. Then in PHP you could use `$x = floor($c / 3); $y = $c - 2 * $x`. You'll have equal intervals 1 to $x, $x+1 to $y and then the rest not always equal to the first inervals $y+1 to $c. Again, all this would work only if you have non-missing ids in the table.